# Ungrouping objects in a pdf file, followed by a modification

Tags: pdf, inkscape

I have a pdf file depicting a number of lines connecting small circles. I want to select all
circles, and change their color and some other properties. Since the number of lines and circles is high, I tried Object->Ungroup, but after trying to modify the properties, the properties of lines also changed.

Could I apply the changes to circles only?

Comment: There is, as far as I know, no way in Inkscape to only select objects of a certain type; however, if you were to save the imported document as SVG, then it might be possible to do it programmatically. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, that would help. Inkscape provides a possibility to save files as SVG. How could I do it then?

Comment: Not entirely sure - just guiding you based on (a) Inkscape can't do this in its existing UI afaik, and (b) this site is only for programming questions. If you're open to a programmatic solution, there's several avenues I'd try. Firstly, save as SVG and open the XML doc out in a text editor, and see how to distinguish the items you want from the items you don't - based on object type, or maybe object id (naming)? You could use a scripting language (what are you familiar with?) to load the XML doc and make changes based on the property you identify above.

Comment: Furthermore, Inkscape has a plugin system, and also a verb command language accessible from the CLI. Those both might be worthy of research. To garner more substantial answers, I wonder - would you paste a snippet of SVG code in your question? If you can show what bits are circles and what bits are not, that would help. And lastly - what system are you on? If you have no language preference (PHP, Ruby, Python etc) then someone may suggest something based on your OS (e.g. PHP on Linux).